# Show all products except items in the cart - Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

My aim is to show all products except the items in my cart essentially related items. I've tried several things but I just keep hitting a dead end.

So far:

This lists the product ids of each item in my cart:

```
{% assign all_product_ids = cart.items | map: 'product_id'| uniq %}

<pre>Product ids: {{ all_product_ids }}</pre>
```

This was my ureka moment however it's hardcoded, *there must be a way to make it dynamic*

```
 {% for item in cart.items %}
{% if item.product.id == 1323872092227 %}
    <div><h1>Nice sunglasses</h1></div><br> 
{% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

Still trying to get this to work

```
  {% assign cart_item_ids = cart.items | map: 'product_id' %} // get array of cart item ids 

{% for product in collections['all'].products%}
{% if cart_item_ids contains product.product_id  %} // check if current product in loop's id is not in the array of cart_item_ids
   <pre>Hi I'm in your cart</pre>
 {% else %}
  <pre>Hi I'm not in your cart</pre>
{% endif%}
{% endfor %}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you kindly

Comment: When you hardcoded the value it worked, i guess the problem in `product.id`. Are you sure `product.id` has the id of the product? (console.log it or render it in html)

Comment: I've edited my code, to show where I've got to now

Comment: You didn't answer the question in my first comment. **`map` creates a string out of each array element’s value, doesn't create an array**